# Differentiability of $f(x+iy)=|x|+i|y|$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

> I am trying to find where the function $f(x+iy)=|x|+i|y|$ is differentiable and then determine where it is analytic.

I have been using the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show where a function is differentiable. I first tried to determine
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(|x|\right)$$
via the definition of differentiability. I considered $f(z)=|\operatorname{Re}(z)|$, so
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|\operatorname{Re}(z)+\operatorname{Re}(h)|-|\operatorname{Re}(z)|}{h} \\
&\leq\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|\operatorname{Re}(h)|}{h} \\
&=\lim_{(u,v)\to (0,0)} \frac{|u|}{u+iv}
\end{align}
But I don't think the approach I am taking is correct. A hint/solution on how to solve this question would be very helpful.

Comment: You can just consider the partial derivatives. Remember the real and imaginary parts are real-valued functions

Comment: For $|x|$, do I need to consider $x\geq 0, \ x<0$?

Comment: It's the same as in the derivative in single variable calculus. The same answer as "what is the derivative of $f(x) =|x|$"

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. If $f(x)=|x|$, then 
\begin{align}
f'(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
                1 & \hspace{5mm} x>0 \\
                -1 & \hspace{5mm} x<0 \\
                \text{undefined} & \hspace{5mm} x=0 \\
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align} right? So in this case, do the Couchy-Riemann equations hold if $x,y>0$ and $x,y<0$? The equations would not hold in the cases where $x>0, y<0$ and $x<0, y>0$ as $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R^2}$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\neq\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes you got it right. Btw another way to look at this is, $f(z) = z$ in the first quadrant, $-\bar{z}$ in second quadrant and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sufficient to consider $x$ and $y$ in four quadrant. In the first and third quadrant you have $xy>0$ and the function will be $f(z)=z$ or $f(z)=-z$ which are analytic. In the second and fourth quadrant you have $xy<0$, so the function will be $f(z)=\bar{z}$ or $f(z)=-\bar{z}$ which aren't analytic. Simply you can consider what happens on axis.